# Apply peicewise function for each element in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame of the type:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 5 6
...
```

I have a list of functions of the same length as one of the rows, for example,

```py
a = lambda x: x**2
b = lambda x: x**3
c = lambda x: x
d = lambda x: x+1
funcs = [a,b,c,d]
```

If applied to the DataFrame above it should output

```
1 8 3 5
1 8 5 7
...
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with dictionary by columns names and functions:

```
df = df.agg(dict(zip(df.columns, funcs)))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  8  3  5
1  1  8  5  7
```

**Details**:

```
print (dict(zip(df.columns, funcs)))
{0: <function <lambda> at 0x000000000DD10310>,
 1: <function <lambda> at 0x0000000010D58040>, 
 2: <function <lambda> at 0x0000000010D580D0>, 
 3: <function <lambda> at 0x0000000010D58160>}
```